# create an epic under an epic

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is there a way to create an epic under an epic on jira ?

Example:
I have on jira this Epic : 'Improvement Process.'

I want to create many under epics like 'Quality' , 'Algorithm', 'Security'.

```
----- >Improuvement Process
------------------------------------->Quality
--------------------------------------------> Stories
------------------------------------------------> Tasks 
------------------------------------->Algorithm
--------------------------------------------> Stories
------------------------------------------------> Tasks
------------------------------------->Security
--------------------------------------------> Stories
------------------------------------------------> Tasks
```

Is there a way to do this ? Thxs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jira has a rich set of classifications base on various needs, which can be exploited to serve any(read it most) business needs. With my experience, I think you can also utilize the existing set of entities to fulfill your need.
How would I try to solve the above business need?

- Epic: Improvement Process

  1. Stories
  2. Tasks
- Component: Quality
- Component: Algorithm
- Component: Security

The component can be added to any of the issue types (Stories, Tasks) to categories them together based on their nature of work i.e (Quality, Algorithm, Security).